# Groovy error when doing a gradle refresh in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to configure Eclipse 4.5 with Gradle and Groovy. I have a more-or-less identical config (excepting later Eclipse version) as a colleague's in terms of Gradle and Groovy add-ons. But when I run Gradle->Refresh All I get a recurring error:

"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'canon-qa'.
org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory"

I've tried changing the Groovy compiler version, but nothing fixes the problem and the error message doesn't give me a lot to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried configuring Eclipse 4.5.1 with the Groovy plugin found in the Eclipse marketplace (Groovy-Eclipse for Juno/Indigo 2.7.1) and ran into similar problems as you (Java Builder errors when trying to compile the Groovy code).

In order to resolve it, I had to stop using the marketplace plugin and install the groovy plugin for Eclipse 4.5 following instructions from https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki (update url  http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/).

Not sure if this will help you but it resolved my issues.